# what is good reactjs development ide?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am finding the IDE for React.JS development which help out regarding syntax like other programming languages.

It should highlight syntax errors of React.js

Comment: A quick search for "reactjs ide" will give you plenty of resources on the topic

Comment: Fair warning: I am going to down-vote EVERY SINGLE "ANSWER" to this question as it SHOULD BE CLOSED not answered -- just look at the close vote reasons, this one IS AS PLAIN AS DAY

Comment: This is technical question just a real developer can understand. and @francium when we search in google lot of articles will come but with ads and so on. So 70% things not to the point. that was the main reason to ask on stack overflow.

Comment: It may indeed be a question for developers, but this is not the right place to ask it. You don't like ads, get an adblocker, I recommend ublock origin. A page has shjt advice, go to the next link

Comment: That's the point when we visit lot of links, it waste lot of time. ads blocker create problems some time when we have development of ad scripts in our application.

Comment: @AshfaqMuhammad Just please don't argue, look at the reason I chose to vote to close the question, and move on understanding that this is not a proper question for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [vim-jsx](https://github.com/mxw/vim-jsx) plug-in in vim editor for reactjs. Syntax highlighting and indenting for JSX.
You can also use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with reactjs extensions which will give you help in syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

I use visual studio code with  [react](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) and [eslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) extensions to get my work done. But there are several IDEs out there on web which has react extensions like atom , webstorm ,sublime etc..